# How to enable Deployment in VS 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest

I receive an error message as below when I try to run a test with `Mstest`:

```
Deployment is currently disabled.
```

Most answers that I get suggest that there exist a `Local.testsettings` file is solution explorer, this is only true in Visual studio 2010 and NOT VS 2012.

How to enable Deployment in VS 2012?